# how to create a subcolumn inside a column in Gtk+ using C++

Tags: c++, unix, gtk

I am creating a listview with 5 columns in Gtk+ using C++. I was able to do that. But the problem is, I need subcolumns for the 2nd column which I'm not sure how to proceed.

firstcolumn | second column | third |
            |SC1 | SC2 | SC3|       |
            |    |     |    |       |

Is this possible? Can you suggest how to go about it?